# Regex string (taking out a character and replacing it with a space)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following ***in a helper extension***:

```
return Regex.Replace(str,
"(?<=[a-z])(?<x>[A-Z])|(?<=.)(?<x>[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[^0-9])(?<x>[0-9])(?=.)",
 " $1");
```

Which will effectively take

> WhateverIPutInToIt

and render

> Whatever I Put In To It

except that I would prefer not to capitalize each proper word. However, if I do not capitalize then it will not render with the spaces.

I thought I would instead try to take something like

> Whatever_I_put_into_it

to render what I want. I cannot figure out how to do a regular expression (if its even possible) to strip out the the "underscore" character and replace it with a space.

Any help?

**Update:**
Sorry for not being clear. This is in a helper extension to convert enums I have into something readable. I am using the helper for my dropdownlists and checkboxlists. I have over 10 enums for those, and to do each one individually would be a pain. Was hoping that I could just fix the `Regex.Replace` code at the top to something that would accomplish what I am after.

Mind you, if I do

> YouHave9OrMore

the above `Regex.Replace` will spit out (it splits out the number "9")

> You Have 9 Or More

Thank you all for the quick comments.

Comment: I simple replace perhaps instead of a regex or am I missing something?

Comment: In this case, you could use `"Whatever_I_put_into_it".Replace('_',' ')`?

Comment: `return Regex.Replace(str,"_"," ");` I really don't see what the problem is.

Comment: So, maybe you don't know which one you get as input? By the way, your pattern is ridiculously complex.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough as to what I was using. The `Regex.Replace` code at the top of my question is in a helper extension. It's taking any enum values I have for dropdownlists and making them readable. I have lots of enum values, so parsing each one individually is too hard. So, I just wanted something in that helper that would parse all my enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried your regex with MatchEvaluator parameter?

```
var finalstr = Regex.Replace(
  "WhateverIPutInToIt", 
  "(?<=[a-z])(?<x>[A-Z])|(?<=.)(?<x>[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[^0-9])(?<x>[0-9])(?=.)", 
  me => " " + me.Value.ToLower() // <----
);
```

This would output `Whatever i put in to it`.

OR

YouHave9OrMore ==>  `You have 9 or more`

---

If you make it an extension method you can use it like this

```
var finalstr = System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly.GetString();

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this Enum en)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(en.ToString(), "(?<=[a-z])(?<x>[A-Z])|(?<=.)(?<x>[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[^0-9])(?<x>[0-9])(?=.)", me => " " + me.Value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. In fact it's your regex :) I just added `me => " " + me.Value.ToLower()`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a regex for that:

```
return str.Replace("_"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to represent webpage titles within URLs and then convert them back for rendering in a legible form on the page itself? In that case, you should use the [`HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode.aspx) and [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) methods. These would respectively convert `"Whatever I Put In To It"` to `"Whatever%20I%20Put%20In%20To%20It"` and back, with the added advantage that other disallowed characters (such as `<` and `>`) are also taken care of, and that most browsers would correctly render the encoded sequences in the address bar.

Comment: No, it's a helper extension that properly displays enums for a checkboxlist or dropdownlist