# Create Space Between Capital Letters and Skip Space Between Consecutive

Tags: c#, linq

I get the way to create space "ThisCourse" to be "This Course"

[Add Space Before Capital Letter By (EtienneT) LINQ Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters)

But i cannot

Create Space Betweeen This "ThisCourseID" to be "This Course ID" without space between "ID"

And Is there a way to do this in Linq ??

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9861239/932418

Comment: Why do you need LINQ for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if it has to be a single linq statement...

```
var s = "ThisCourseIDMoreXYeahY";
s = string.Join(
        string.Empty, 
        s.Select((x,i) => (
             char.IsUpper(x) && i>0 && 
             ( char.IsLower(s[i-1]) || (i<s.Count()-1 && char.IsLower(s[i+1])) )
        ) ? " " + x : x.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output: "This Course ID More X Yeah Y"

Answer (score 4):

```
var s = "ThisCourseID";

for (var i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLower(s[i - 1]) && char.IsUpper(s[i]))
    {
        s = s.Insert(i, " ");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(s); // "This Course ID"
```

You can improve this using StringBuilder if you are going to use this on very long strings, but for your purpose, as you presented it, it should work just fine.

**FIX:**

```
var s = "ThisCourseIDSomething";

for (var i = 1; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLower(s[i - 1]) && char.IsUpper(s[i]) ||
        s[i - 1] != ' ' && char.IsUpper(s[i]) && char.IsLower(s[i + 1]))
    {
        s = s.Insert(i, " ");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(s); // This Course ID Something
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr Yorye, Please, is there a solution to make it with LINQ ??

Comment: +1 for working correctly with the given sample. Note, this won't work for something like "ThisCourseIDMoreWords". The output in this case would be "This Course IDMore Words"

Comment: @Robbie You're right, but it shouldn't be hard to play around with the condition to make it work. Fixed it.

Comment: @HadyShaltout It is possible to implement the same logic with LINQ, but it would be a bad idea since LINQ isn't a tool that suits your needs in this case.

Comment: @YoryeNathan i'd +1 you again but i can't :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need LINQ - but you could 'enumerate' and use lambda to make it more generic...
(though not sure if any of this makes sense)

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string text, Func<char?, char?, char, int?> shouldSplit)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    char? before = null;
    char? before2nd = null;
    foreach (var c in text)
    {
        var where = shouldSplit(before2nd, before, c);
        if (where != null)
        {
            var str = output.ToString();
            switch(where)
            {
                case -1:
                    output.Remove(0, str.Length -1);
                    yield return str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
                    break;
                case 0: default:
                    output.Clear();
                    yield return str;
                    break;
            }
        }
        output.Append(c);
        before2nd = before;
        before = c;
    }
    yield return output.ToString();
}
```

...and call it like this e.g. ...

```
    static IEnumerable<string> SplitLines(this string text)
    {
        return text.Split((before2nd, before, now) =>
        {
            if ((before2nd ?? 'A') == '\r' && (before ?? 'A') == '\n') return 0; // split on 'now'
            return null; // don't split
        });
    }
    static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnCase(this string text)
    {
        return text.Split((before2nd, before, now) =>
        {
            if (char.IsLower(before ?? 'A') && char.IsUpper(now)) return 0; // split on 'now'
            if (char.IsUpper(before2nd ?? 'a') && char.IsUpper(before ?? 'a') && char.IsLower(now)) return -1; // split one char before
            return null; // don't split
        });
    }
```

...and somewhere...

```
        var text = "ToSplitOrNotToSplitTHEQuestionIsNow";
        var words = text.SplitOnCase();
        foreach (var word in words)
            Console.WriteLine(word);

        text = "To\r\nSplit\r\nOr\r\nNot\r\nTo\r\nSplit\r\nTHE\r\nQuestion\r\nIs\r\nNow";
        words = text.SplitLines();
        foreach (var word in words)
            Console.WriteLine(word);
```

:)